# "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server." error msg

Tags: php, payment-gateway

i m working on a online payment module in php. I got the "Forbidden  You don't have permission to access / on this server." error msg when i make the payment and redirected to bank site only for one registered user.
For others user module is working fine, means they makes their payment properly. 
i m confused why only for a one perticular  registered user this msg is coming ???

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server , this is some thing related to file permission

Comment: but my module is working fine for other registered users. means others user had made their payment using my payment module . only one user getting the "Forbidden Error msg"..and unable to make payment using my module.

Answer (score 0):

- http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/403error.htm
  please check this site thi site help full you to forbidden error

Comment: thnks for suppot..

i think bankers block his ip or email id ...thats why that perticular user registered with his email ..are not able to make the payment...